# High CPU caused by sp1 process

Tags: battery, resource-monitoring

I have a Samsung Galaxy Alpha and I have a problem. Sometimes a process named sp1 starts to run 100% on a single thread, causing a constant 12% of CPU (I have 8 cores).

I don't know how I can understand what applicaion is related to this process.
This problem is very annoying because if you don't see it in time all the battery will be drawn soon.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you already opened a terminal to inspect this process' dir in /proc? Like cwd, environ, fd?

Comment: @ott-- good advice, I'll give a try